# Extracting data from a specific row from .csv files does not work

Tags: python, csv

I am making a python program which loops through all `.csv` files in a folder, and copies the 2nd rule from each of these files. When I try to extract data from the 2nd row from a `.csv` file, it does not work for some reason.

I tried to instantly read it from the `.csv` file, but that did not work. After that I tried to first write all the content to a `.txt` file and then read it. This dit not work as well.

This is my current code:

```
import os
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
from itertools import islice
from io import StringIO

#select folder + file
root = filedialog.Tk()
root.withdraw()

#folder which contains all the .csv files
target_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

#file where necessary content from .csv files gets wrote to
target_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

#Loop through all files in target folder and grab .csv files
content = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(target_folder):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + filename
        
        if filename.lower().startswith('autopilot'):
            with open(os.path.join(subdir, filename)) as f:
                data = f.read()
                print(data)
```

It now outputs all the data, but I want it to only output the 2nd row of each `.csv` file.

Comment: Hi Denver! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: would you be able to add the first few rows of your csv to your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You read and print all file^

```
print(data)
```

change to

```
data = f.readlines()
print(data[1])  # print second line
```

read more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073162/difference-in-read-readline-and-readlines-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I had to change it to print(data[2]), it now works!

Comment: @Denver *print(data[2])* will print the third line - not the second

Comment: I know, but somehow if I use data[2], it prints the needed data

Answer (score 0):

You need to read lines from the chosen file then check that there are at least 2 lines before printing the second one.

Use *glob* to simplify file selection

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from glob import glob
import os

source_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

for file in glob(os.path.join(source_folder, '*.csv')):
    if file.lower().startswith('autopilot'):
        with open(file) as data:
            if len(rows := data.readlines()) > 1:
                print(rows[1])
```